# Solaris - (httpd) pkcs11_softtoken: Keystore access failed

Tags: apache, solaris, keystore, pkcs#11

I'm having a problem with a Solaris server I inherited that has been happening for years. (The release is `Solaris 10 5/09 s10x_u7wos_08 X86`)

Every few seconds in my `/var/adm/messages` file I get the following line:

```
httpd[2910]: [ID 218067 user.debug] pkcs11_softtoken: Keystore access failed
```

I'm pretty sure this is what is causing my core dumps that are filling up my hard drive causing my database to stop functioning, so I'd love to figure this out.

My apologies if I did not provide enough information, I really have no clue what the error means so I don't know what would be relevant to post. Thanks!

*Disclaimer: I am a programmer by profession, not a server administrator... so please be gentle.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not store certificates in Solaris PKCS11 token, then simply disable/comment `SSLCryptoDevice pkcs11` in Apache config. Note that Solaris PKCS11 token do correctly work just with Solaris bundled OpenSSL. On X86 it doesn't bring much performance improvement too, to use this token. On SPARC since T1 it has its meaning, cause there are hardware accelerators on CPU. Refer to `man cryptoadm` for Solaris token details.

Comment: Thank you very much! Commented out that line, gave 'er a restart, and no more error message!